# Cannot resolve symbol CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

I can use coordinator layout in my xml files but when I tried to import it in my java class it said "Cannot resolve symbol CoordinatorLayout while other classes in the same packages work fine.

Screenshot is shown below:
[image]

Dependencies:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try  this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
```