# add snackbar in android activity from asynktask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

From `main` activity i call this background process. here in this background there is `onprexecute` method there is an `if else` condition in `else` part i need to add a `Snackbar`

```
public class background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ConnectivityManager cm;
    private String jsonurl, jsonstring;
    public static String listRequest;
    private mobile_form mform;
    private Context ctx;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    background (Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        cm = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        progressbar = new ProgressBar(ctx);
        progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#039BE5"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        mform = new mobile_form();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        jsonurl = "https://crackstrickblog.000webhostapp.com/json_get_data.php";
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setContentView(progressbar);
        }
        else {
// here i need to add snackbar like this
//Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isConnected) {
                ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, mobile_form.class));
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: then add it, what is the problem?

Comment: here in  this.findViewById(android.R.id.content) it shows findViewById as cannot resolve method findViewById(int)

Comment: that's right because AsyncTask has no such method. You need to pass the View for example in the constructor parameters same way as you do with the Context, and use it in your Snackbar.

Comment: can you tell how to pass it

Comment: `background (Context ctx){` -> `background (Context ctx, View view){`. Then store the view into a field, and pass in the Snackbar: `Snackbar.make(view, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: thanks a lot. i need one more help

Comment: i am trying to check internet connectivity when clicking a button if no internet connection it shows this snackbar. when i click retry on snackbar i need to retry the button which i clicked before

Answer (score 1):

This `Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

will not work. `findViewById` is a method of activity class not of `AsyncTask`.

Use interface as a callback.

```
interface Callback {

public void showSnackBar();
}
```

In AsyncTask

```
private Callback callback;
```

Then

```
public background (Context ctx){

callback =(Callback) ctx;
```

Then in onPreExecute

```
 else {
     if(callback!=null)
      callback.showSnackbar();

    }
```

In activity class implement the interface and the method

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback {
```

Then

```
@Override
public void showSnackBar()
{
  // show snack bar in activity
}
```

You could also use some event bus mechanism instead of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a context use your activity to find view in that context as you are in asynchronous class, you don't have access to your activity view.

```
 Snackbar.make(MainActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: MainActivity is not an enclosing class

Comment: Use proper activity or fragment where your view with id `content` is.

Comment: i need it in main activity and its a proper activity

Comment: So you should have a view with id `content` in your `Main` activity `layout.xml` file, add your xml code here if you are not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet to display a basic SnackBar is shown below:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "www.journaldev.com", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

In the above snippet make() method accepts three parameters:

coordinatorLayout : It is the root layout of the activity

www.journaldev.com : This is the message to be appear on snackbar, and we can customise it with our own message

Snackbar.LENGH_LONG : This is last parameter which is the time limit how long snackbar to be displayed

show() method is used to display the SnackBar on the screen.

Does this help you?

Comment: Thats a duplicated question. [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206181/cannot-resolve-symbol-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: my gradle has 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0' still now shows same

Comment: could you try this doc http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/
maybe it helps you to check where is the fail.
Also @Raghunandan answer seems very well explained.